# D3.js tooltips not displaying correctlty when generated with Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, d3.js

I want to make some tooltips visible in my d3 map. The tooltips are column charts generated by Highcharts regarding the chosen city. The trick is that everything is displaying correctly (axis, labels ...) except that the columns are not visible!

Here my d3 code (only the relevant parts):

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("id","tooltip")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("visibility", "hidden");

cities.on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
    d3.select(this).style('fill', '#95a5a6');
    tooltip.html(zoomCityComm(d))
    return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")})
   .on("mousemove", function(d, i){
   return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 130) + "px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX - 120) + "px");
```

})
}

The function zoomCityComm is HighCharts (example of data: [5,10]):

```
function zoomCityComm(d) {

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart : {
        renderTo: 'tooltip',
        type: 'column',
        width:200,
        height:200,
        plotBackgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
        zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
        text: "TOTO"
    },
    legend: {
     enabled: false
    },  
        xAxis: {
     categories: ['In','Out']
    },
    yAxis: {
    title: {
         text: 'Sum',
         style: {
             color: '#4572A7'
         }
    },
    labels: {
        style: {
        color: '#4572A7'
        }
    },

},
series:[{color: '#4572A7',data: res}]
        });

return document.getElementById("tooltip").innerHTML;
```

}

When the graph is displayed in a "normal" div within the document, it appears correctly.

Sorry if my explanations are not clear but ask me for some details if needed.

Thanks
Cyril

Comment: You may need to set the [`z-index`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) to make your tooltip appear on top of everything else.

Comment: The tooltip appears but without the bars. The rest is correct. Even when I scroll the DOM the bars are there with a z-index of 0.1. I really don't understand.

Comment: Try setting the `z-index` to something higher.

Comment: I put the zIndex of data to 100 with no effects. Here the html concerning a column which is not appearing: <rect fill="#4572A7" x="15.5" y="43.5" width="30" height="87" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" rx="0" ry="0"></rect>

Comment: Could you post the complete code somewhere please?

Comment: I sent you the documents. Hope you will see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the HTML content of the `div` twice, as highcharts renders it itself. In your `mouseover` handler function, it is enough to do

```
zoomCityComm(d);
```

instead of

```
tooltip.html(zoomCityComm(d));
```

For the interested, here's what's happening. Setting the HTML of the tooltip `div` from the return value of the function captures the first animation frame that highchart uses to grow the bars. As it is the first frame, the height of the bars is still 0 -- that is, the bars are there, but not visible because they have essentially no height. Replacing the HTML of the `div` means that the animation won't work anymore, as the elements that would be animated have been replaced.